# Download image from url and put in buffer

Tags: c++

I get the url for an image at runtime and I'd like to load it into some kind of continguous buffer in memory, arrays or vectors would be perfectly fine. I can only use the std and boost libraries and my google-fu is currently failing me.

EDIT: For people in the future, this is probably something you want to use a third-party library for.

Comment: Why can't you use any third-party libraries?

Comment: @eriatarka84: Corporate coding standards discourage it.

Comment: Ok. It's a bit silly, but I edited my response to restrict the choice to Boost libraries.

Comment: @JoshuaSnider Gotta love corporate coding standards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**If you can use additional libraries:**

[cpp-netlib](http://cpp-netlib.org/) to download the image data

Any C++ image library to decode the image data; e.g., [CImg](http://cimg.sourceforge.net/)

**Without non-Boost libraries:**

Hack your own minimal HTTP client on top of Boost::ASIO (basically, just send a /GET request and read the response).

Use [GIL](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/libs/gil/doc/index.html) to decode the image.

This approach will be much less reliable though.